# PHP Session always working

Tags: php, variables, session

I've got an if statement to check if a variable within the $_SESSION is active and set, and if it is then a message is returned to the user. Here's my header.php:

```
<?php
    $conn = HIDDEN;

    session_start();
    $username = '';
    $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
    ?>

    <header>
        <!DOCTYPE html>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style/main.css">
        <title>webshop</title>

    </header>

    <div id="LogIn">
        <?php
        if (isset($_SESSION['username']))
        {
            echo "its working";
        } else {
            ?><form class="form1" method="post" action="" id="form1">
                <fieldset>
                    <ul>
                        <p>Please enter your username to continue to the webshop.</p>
                        <label for="name">User Name:</label><span><input type="text" name="username" placeholder="User Name" class="required" role="input" aria-required="true"/></span>
                        <input class="submit .transparentButton" value="Next" type="submit" name="Submit"/>
                    </ul>
                    <br/>
                </fieldset>
            </form>
        <?php } ?>
    </div>

    <?php
    if (isset($_POST['Submit'])) {
        $_SESSION['username'] = $_POST['username'];
    }
    ?>

    <?php
    if (isset($_POST['Submit'])) {
        $_SESSION['username'] = $_POST['username'];

        // Use the following code to print out the variables.
        echo 'Session: '.$_SESSION['username'];
        echo '<br>';
        echo 'POST: '.$_POST['username'];
    }
?>
```

The first time running, or before the user logs out (to be implemented later), the site should prompt for a username to be entered and then upon refreshing the page the welcome message should be display.

As of right now the code simply returns "it's working" despite no variable in $username existing. The code:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['Submit'])) {
       $_SESSION['username'] = $_POST['username'];

        // Use the following code to print out the variables.
        echo 'Session: '.$_SESSION['username'];
        echo '<br>';
        echo 'POST: '.$_POST['username'];
    }
?>
```

should print out the variable underneath the welcome message, or nothing at all if it's empty. As of right now, the welcome message "it's working" is displayed always but **no variables are in $username**. Can anyone tell me why?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: doesn't look like the session was started elsewhere

Comment: session_start() is always on the first line. just a quick glance, goodnight

Comment: Didn't make any different, I moved it to the first line and the same happens. @Fred-ii- could you explain what you mean please? To my knowledge the session is active, I can't see why else I would need to start another one.

Comment: your last body of code doesn't contain `session_start();` in there. If you're using it, please update your question. I deleted my answer. Use error reporting.

Comment: `<?php
if (isset($_POST['Submit'])) {
       $_SESSION['username'] = $_POST['username'];` - Where's `session_start();` in here? That's what I meant about it. My answer contained it, but I deleted it. Let me know if you want me to undelete it. It was the first answer submitted.

Comment: @Fred-ii- if I add in session_start() to that it returns an error saying it's already using a session and will ignore the new call.

Comment: Ok, I see what you did in your question. You included the last body of code as part of your full code. I thought that was another file. That's why I thought it was missing.

Comment: @Fred-ii- also that section of code is functioning as intended, it's returning the session variable $username without session_start() in, with it in it simply returns an error and ignores the session_start();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$_SESSION['username']` is SET/NULL but is EMPTY you should try !empty() instead if `isset()`. See below.

```
<?php
if (!empty($_SESSION['username']))
{
    echo "its working";
} else {
    ?><form class="form1" method="post" action="" id="form1">
        <fieldset>
            <ul>
                <p>Please enter your username to continue to the webshop.</p>
                <label for="name">User Name:</label><span><input type="text" name="username" placeholder="User Name" class="required" role="input" aria-required="true"/></span>

                <input  class="submit .transparentButton" value="Next" type="submit" name="Submit"/>

            </ul>
            <br/>
        </fieldset>
    </form>
<?php } ?>
```

**EDIT 2**
As to the comment.

IF statement needed to tell if there was a submit if there was don't display the form else display the form. See below Code

```
<?php
    $conn = ""; //HIDDEN kept throwing error whilst I was testing

    session_start();
    $username = '';
    $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
    ?>

    <header>
        <!DOCTYPE html>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style/main.css">
        <title>webshop</title>

    </header>

    <div id="LogIn">
        <?php
            if (isset($_POST['Submit'])) {
                $_SESSION['username'] = $_POST['username'];

                $_SESSION['username'] = $_POST['username'];

                // Use the following code to print out the variables.
                echo 'Session: '.$_SESSION['username'];
                echo '<br>';
                echo 'POST: '.$_POST['username'];

            } else {

        if (!empty($_SESSION['username']))
        {
            echo "its working";
        } else {
            ?><form class="form1" method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>" id="form1">
                <fieldset>
                    <ul>
                        <p>Please enter your username to continue to the webshop.</p>
                        <label for="name">User Name:</label><span><input type="text" name="username" placeholder="User Name" class="required" role="input" aria-required="true"/></span>

                        <input  class="submit transparentButton" value="Next" type="submit" name="Submit"/> //removed css selector .
                    </ul>
                    <br/>
                </fieldset>
            </form>
        <?php } } ?>


    </div>
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. I've used it and it's worked, mostly. It's now returning the variable $username correctly but still parsing the form instead of the welcome message. I've got the test in the bottom of the OP to see if $username has the correct variable in and it's working, any idea what might be happening?

Comment: @JayGould So does the form show now? If you fill out the username field does it return anything?

Comment: the form shows and the test (at the bottom of the OP) shows the $username variable with the value given in the form, but the form is constantly visible even though the if statement says if $username isn't empty then don't parse it. The test I included at the bottom show me the variable being set (and the ability to change it too), so I'm really not sure what's happening.

Comment: Would it be because I'm declaring `$username = '';` at the top by any chance? It's emptying the variable each time header is ran...

Comment: @JayGould I have added an EDIT 2 which should only display the form if submit is set.

Comment: Thanks that's working. Another problem is that the session variable isn't carrying over to another page. I've included header.php (where the above code is stored) and included it in `cart.php` before anything else, but it's gone back to prompting for a username and the variable isn't there. Any idea why?

Comment: @JayGould could you edit your question and add the cart.php code? also have you tried to include session_start(); on the top line of cart.php?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96272/discussion-between-jamie-sterling-and-jay-gould).

Answer (score 0):

The isset() checks only whether the variable is set or not and it returns true since it is initialized to null string. Here you have to use !empty().

```
if (isset($_SESSION['username']) && !empty($_SESSION['username'])) {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a quick solution is to change

```
  if (isset($_SESSION['username']))
```

to

```
 if (strlen($_SESSION['username']) > 0)
```

That will work. Im guessing it because technically u did set username so it isset but if u check the length u know its not empty